# How do we render anti aliased 2D Polygons?

Tags: algorithm, graphics, 2d, antialiasing

So I started learning CG and its algorithms and I wonder how we can render anti aliased polygons. I know that we can use Xiaolin Wu's line algorithm and its extension for circles to render anti aliased lines and circles. Of course we then also can render arcs and ellipses but how do we anti alias e.g. a B-spline?

And furthermore, how can we integrate anti aliasing into the scanline algorithm to render filled polygons?

Comment: how does `B-spline` & `polygon` any different than `lines and circles` ?

Comment: I don't know, that's why I'm asking :)